# _path_files and compadd ignore-files parameter

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

What is the format for the -F option of `_path_files` and `compadd`?

I'm passing several directories to `_path_files`:

```
_path_files -W "($base_directories)" -/
```

But some of those directory trees I don't want to complete for this particular command.

The documentation I can find for `_path_files` says it accepts a `-F` option—just like `compadd`, but I can't find the format to pass them in.

Twiddling around hasn't been very fruitful either.

I've tried, for example,

```
_path_files -W "($base_directories)" -/ -F shared; # shared still shows up
_path_files -W "($base_directories)" -/ -F "(shared)"; # barfs on that guy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks correct if you want to ignore `shared` at the root of the directory tree, i.e. if you're ignoring one of the `$base_directories`. But if you meant to ignore `shared` somewhere deeper in the hierarchy, you need `-F "(shared **shared)"`. You can also put the patterns in an array, which will reduce the quoting pains.

```
local -a ignored base_directories
base_directories=(…)
ignored=(shared '*/shared')
_path_files -W base_directories -/ -F ignored
```

There are examples in the standard distribution in `_cvs` and `_darcs`.

If this doesn't help, try investigating what's going on by adding `set -x` and `set +x` around the problematic code, or `setopt local_options xtrace` (a.k.a `set -x` and change options only for the duration of the current function).

Comment: hmmm. I thought I had tried all that. but it worked! thanks!